# Python Pandas Conditional Sum and subtract previous row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new here and i need some help with python pandas.
I need help creating a new column where i get sum of another columns + previous row of this calculated row.

This is my example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'column0': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'x'],
'column1': [50, 100, 30, 0, 30, 80, 0], 
'column2': [0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 30],
})
print(df)
    column0  column1  column2
 0       x       50        0
 1       x      100        0
 2       y       30        0
 3       x        0       10
 4       y       30        0
 5       y       80        0
 6       x        0       30
```

I have used loc to filter this DataFrame like this:

```
 df = df.loc[df['column0'] == 'x']
 df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now...when i try to get the output, i don't get correct result:

```
df['Result'] = df['column1'] + df['column2']
df['Result'] = df['column1'] + df['column2'] + df['Result'].shift(1)

print(df)
   column0  column1  column2  Result
0       x       50        0     NaN
1       x      100        0   100.0
2       x        0       10    10.0
3       x        0       30    30.0
```

I just want this output....

```
   column0  column1  column2  Result
0       x       50        0     50
1       x      100        0   150.0
2       x        0       10   160.0
3       x        0       30   190.0
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. Consider adding some example input/output dataframes so we can follow more clearly

Comment: Hi. I added a image. Thanks,

Comment: It's better to add your dataframe in code/text, instead of a picture. You can do this by df.head(5).to_dict() and copy/paste the output as code here. It's also helpful if you post the output you're looking for as code/text into your question. This really helps answering your question. I posted my answer below.

Comment: Thanks. Next time i will do that. It is my first post here. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to calculate a cumulative sum of the column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column1': [50, 100, 30, 0, 30, 80, 0], 
    'column2': [0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 30],
})

df['column3'] = df['column1'].cumsum() - df['column2'].cumsum()
```

This results in:

```
    column1 column2 column3
0    50     0        50
1   100     0       150
2    30     0       180
3     0    10       170
4    30     0       200
5    80     0       280
6     0    30       250
```